# Google Admob ads integration

Tags: android, admob

```
MobileAds.initialize()
```

We have to write this code by Google Admob in all the activities of the app or only in the Launcher Activity?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Please add some more details and code and descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make one call irrespective of the number of AdMob accounts or AdUnit being used in your app.

The Mobile Ads SDK take a few milliseconds to initialize itself and AdSDK now have provided `initialize(..)` method to call it way before you even call your first ad. Once that is done, there would not be any added load time for your first request. If you do not call this, then your very first AdRequest would take a few milliseconds more as it first needs to initialize itself.